# Target pages using a specific page template

Tags: customization, conditional-content

I need to target all pages using a specific page template with a conditional tag (like is_page()). Anyone done something like that before?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do to those pages?

Answer (score 2):

Almost guessed it. :) There is native [`is_page_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Is_a_Page_Template) function.

Comment: Thanks! I skimmed that codex page, but I must have missed it.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is correct. This stimulates the good wills around here :)